# Extract attribute's value with XPATH in a special case

Tags: java, xml, design-patterns, xpath, tags

hi i need help to extract information from XML with xpath.

I will use Xpath to extract the value of the attribute of one Tag that start with a generic keywork:

```
<st:Testprova id='abcd'>
  ....
</st>

  or

<st:Test1prova id='defg'>
  ....
</st>
```

I used that Xpath expression:

```
"//*[contains(.,'prova')]/@ID"
```

but does not work. Can you help me??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `@ID` instead of `@id`, this is case sensitive. Besides, you should use `name()` to retrieve the node-name.

This XPath expression

```
//*[contains(name(),'prova')]/@id
```

returns `abcd` and `defg`

Although your XML is not correct, it should be:

```
<st:Testprova id='abcd'>
  ....
</st:Testprova>
<st:Test1prova id='defg'>
  ....
</st:Test1prova>
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct function to be used in this case is `matches()`.

contains() can return true even for node names like

```
Testprova
Prodprova
UATprova
provaTest
```

and others which ever contains the word prova.

But if you know the pattern with which the node name will be, then matches() functions filters out exactly the desired nodes.

So if i assume a digit might appear between both the words, the xpath can be written like below

```
//*[matches(name(), '^Test[0-9]?prova$')]//@ID
```

**Note:** matches function is part of Xpath2.0 and will not work in Xpath1.0